# Set HTTP proxy in Windows programmatically

Tags: winapi, uwp, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, mdns

I'm trying to see if it is possible to set HTTP proxy configuration programmatically from my C++/WinRT code. I found that one can get the current proxy configuration with `NetworkInformation.GetProxyConfigurationAsync` from [UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getproxyconfigurationasync?view=winrt-18362#Windows_Networking_Connectivity_NetworkInformation_GetProxyConfigurationAsync_Windows_Foundation_Uri_). But is it possible to change it?

My goal is to find a proxy server on the local network and set it up for Edge (or any other browser in the system) as the HTTP proxy. So, that afterward, for whoever is using a browser on that system, all requests would go through the proxy server.

I don't seek to use UWP or any application model in particular. Any way of achieving my goal (that described above) from C++ code would work.

Comment: I searched the UWP documents about this, but no luck. I'm not sure if we can set the proxy that could be used as the HTTP proxy for browser, I will continue to try it.

Comment: Here is a [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/setting-wininet-proxy-configurations-in-winhttp) about how to setting the Proxy Configuration by using win32, maybe you can try it.

Comment: A highly sandboxed application model like UWP is *very* unlikely to be able to make *global* system changes. Are you mistaking the Windows Runtime for the Universal Windows Platform?

Comment: @linspectable I'm not sure which SDK is better for this task. I know that I would like to use standard C++, so my choice was C++/WinRT, but I assume I can use UWP in there too. If there is a way to do the task without UWP I'd appreciate if you point me to the right direction. An example in UWP documentation is the closest I could get to what I want to achieve.

Comment: UWP is an application model. The Windows Runtime is the API surface. C++/WinRT is a language projection for the Windows Runtime. The Windows Runtime can be used from any application model (including, but not limited to UWP). You can access the Windows Runtime from a classic Win32 application just fine. It's just not clear what you are looking for. If you *are* writing a UWP application, you probably cannot change system settings. If you are targeting any other application model, you probably can change system settings (provided the app has the required permissions).

Comment: Hey @IInspectable thank you for the full answer. I'd like to be able to update global Web Proxy settings. Is there a way to do it in Win32 or any other application model?

Comment: You could try to create a win32 application to update proxy settings.